# jarsigner error: keystore load: Invalid keystore format

Tags: maven

I used original keystore and try to sign it using Maven jar signer plugin.
Getting exception as jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Invalid keystore format

```
<configuration>
<archiveDirectory>target/encrypte.jar</archiveDirectory>
<excludes>
<exclude>**/S*.jar</exclude>
</excludes>
<includes>
<include>**/*.jar</include>
</includes>
<keystore>src/main/resources/Cert.pfx</keystore>
<alias>*****</alias>
<storepass>****</storepass>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to specify the keystore format because the default is normally jks. Please try to add

```
<storetype>pkcs12</storetype>
```

to your maven configuration.

If this did not help try to have look into your cert with:

```
keytool -list -v -storetype pkcs12 -storepass **** -keystore src/main/resources/Cert.pfx
```

If this did not work maybe something is wrong with the certificate like strange special chars.